# Field name in model versus field name in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named `end`. It works fine in my development environment where I use SQLite.

But in production I get an error because of PostgreSQL where `end` is a reserved word.

I don't want to rename the field in the model, because there are too many files to edit.

Instead, I want to declare a mapping rule so that field name in model stay "end" but name of this field in database became `end_date`.

How I can do it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I don't want to edit all my files. So I ask is it possible to declare mapping rule for ActiveRecord? Smth like:
map_as(model_field_name, database_field_name).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, long-term, is almost certainly to suck it up and change all your Ruby code to use `end_date`. Obviously, that's going to be tedious because `end` is a Ruby keyword too, meaning Search & Replace won't Just Work; so if you really can't face it try this.

Change the name in the database, then add the following two methods to your model:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base

  def end
    end_date
  end

  def end=(val)
    self.end_date = val
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not exactly what I need. Main problem is that this model used in JSON view, and this JSON is used by 3rd-party Javascript libraries (FullCalendar), which needs exactly "end" field.